# How to change the default metric plot in SageMaker from time to epoch using CloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sagemaker

I am using Amazon SageMaker to train a machine learning model, and I have noticed that by default, the CloudWatch plots metrics such as accuracy and loss against time.

However, I would like to plot these metrics against the epochs instead.

This is how I define the "metric_definitions" in my sagemaker estimator:

```
metric_definitions=[
                    {'Name':'train:loss', 'Regex':'train_loss=(.*?)]'},
                    {'Name':'validation:loss', 'Regex':'val_loss=(.*?),'},                    
                ],
```

What do I need to do to see the x-axis in epoch and not only time?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no way to do this as of Feb 2024 (AWS support are you listening?). One slightly inconvenient workaround is:

1. Download data as .csv with your metrics and epoch selected (I would add `epoch` to your `metric_definitions` array, see below)
2. Chart it out with another plotting tool.

```py
metric_definitions=[
    {'Name': 'train_loss', 'Regex': "'loss': ([0-9]+(.|e\-)[0-9]+),?"},
    {'Name': 'learning_rate', 'Regex': "'learning_rate': ([0-9]+(.|e\-)[0-9]+),?"},
    {'Name': 'val_loss', 'Regex': "'eval_loss': ([0-9]+(.|e\-)[0-9]+),?"},
    {'Name': 'val_accuracy', 'Regex': "'eval_accuracy': ([0-9]+(.|e\-)[0-9]+),?"},
    {'Name': 'val_f1', 'Regex': "'eval_f1': ([0-9]+(.|e\-)[0-9]+),?"},
    {'Name': 'val_precision', 'Regex': "'eval_precision': ([0-9]+(.|e\-)[0-9]+),?"},
    {'Name': 'val_recall', 'Regex': "'eval_recall': ([0-9]+(.|e\-)[0-9]+),?"},
    {'Name': 'val_runtime', 'Regex': "'eval_runtime': ([0-9]+(.|e\-)[0-9]+),?"},
    {'Name': 'val_samples_per_second', 'Regex': "'eval_samples_per_second': ([0-9]+(.|e\-)[0-9]+),?"},
    {'Name': 'epoch', 'Regex': "'epoch': ([0-9]+(.|e\-)[0-9]+),?"}]
```